# Why doesn't the computer have to do a comparison search to find a hash table value?

Tags: hashtable

I'm brushing up on how hash tables work, and so I understand how the hash function calculates a unique (for the purpose of this question) hash table value to go with a stored value, so when the stored value is searched the hash function gives the computer the hash table value.

OK, so now we have the hash table value, but how is this better? Don't we still have to iterate through until we find the matching hash table value?

Comment: Does your "brushing up" not include reading any book or web page that actually shows how hash tables work? The Wikipedia entry on hash tables answers your question.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I was reading [this page](http://www.relisoft.com/book/lang/pointer/8hash.html) when I came up with this question, but in the comments of the answer below someone reminded me how the array index look-up works.

Comment: **yes** it stil has to iterate to find the exact match. However most of the time the hash itself will fall on the correct index, and like Hyde said, it is just a direct memory access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash function will be used to be mapped to an index directly in your array. So no search or iteration is done

Comment: So let's say the hash function gives you '5', so then it's just going to array[5]? How does the computer skip ahead to the 5th index? Maybe I am going out of scope of my question now...

Comment: @ioSamurai Any array access by index is simple memory access: `address_of_array + index * array_element_size`

Comment: @ioSamurai: This answer is completely false. Hashing is not unique, collisions do happen, therefore there is still a linear lookup from the hashed position using a compare functor until the match is found. This is why hash table lookups are said to be "amortized constant time" and not strictly O(1). You should not accept this answer.

Comment: @v.oddou:This OP is about the basic concept of a hash table which the OP did not know.The effects of collisions and how they are handled (linked lists) are not relevant as an answer to this OP.

Answer (score 1):

The hash table is stored in an array.  The hash value is mapped to an array index.  Depending on the implementation, either the hash value is the array index or it is a number from a larger range which is taken modulo the size of the array.

Then once it looks at that spot in the array, it has to check that the value there matches, since multiple values may have the same hash value.  Usually, it actually navigates a linked list of all values which have been hashed to the same spot in the hash table.  This is a much, much shorter list than the full list (especially if the size of the hash table is proportional to the amount of data in it).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different hash tables, each with differing details about the implementation, but the simplest hash table uses a hash code as index into an array:

```
#define TABLESIZE 1000

char **gHashTable[TABLESIZE];

void clearHashTable() {
  memset(gHashTable, 0, sizeof(gHashTable));
}

int calculateHashCode(char *string) {
  int val = 0;
  for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    val += string[i];
  return val;
}

void insertInHash(char *string) {
  int hashCode = calculateHashCode(string);
  gHashTable[hashCode % TABLESIZE] = string;
}

int isInHashTable(char *string) {
  int hashCode = calculateHashCode(string);
  return gHashTable[hashCode % TABLESIZE] != 0;
}
```

Now this simple hash supports fast lookup on strings.  It doesn't handle collisions well, the hash function is terrible, and a number of other problems, but it will work.